# Not reaching to the correct answer using Newton Raphson Method

Tags: python, newton-raphson

I am trying to find the inverse of the following function using Newton Raphson Method:
[(This is the function)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dqq1l.png) by transforming it into [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Kbw5.png). Here, k is a constant, and we know the value of y hence it also becomes a constant and we want to find the value of x.

I tried to write a python code for the same, with around 20000 iterations but it is not converging to the correct value. Can someone give me any hint where am I going wrong. The values of y and k are 0.64 and 0.583 and the first guess for x is 0.4. The expected value of x is 0.651 but even after number of iterations, I am getting -7.88.  This is the first time I am working on such a problem.

Here is the code: (func_ is the differentiation of func)

```
import math

def NTUCalculator(x,y,k):
    func = (x/(1-math.exp(-x))) + ((k*x)/(1-math.exp(-k*x))) - 1 - 1/y
    func_ = (1-math.exp(-x)) - (x*math.exp(-x)) + (k*(1-math.exp(-k*x))) - (k*k*x*math.exp(-k*x))
    return x - (func/func_)

NTU = 0.4

for i in range(20000):
    NTU = NTUCalculator(NTU,0.64,0.583)

NTU
```

[image: Graphfxvsx]

Comment: In the code, shouldn't that y be 1/y ?

Comment: And your derivative is wrong too. See [Wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=d%2Fdx+%28x%2F%281-exp%28-x%29%29+%2Bkx%2F%281-exp%28-kx%29%29++%29)

Comment: I corrected y to 1/y but still it is converging to 0.011832742485227143

Comment: What's `NTU` short for?

Comment: I checked it twice, can you please let me know where exactly is the error in differential?

Comment: You needn't work out the derivative if you use [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steffensen%27s_method) variant.

Comment: NTU is number of transfer units. It is used in Heat exchangers in Mechanical Domain.

Comment: See the wolfram link I gave. You have multiplied away the denominators, which you cannot do since not only are they not the same (some have a k others don't), you also need to know the actual value of the derivative, not just whether or not it is zero.

Answer (score 1):

As Jaap Scherphuis has pointed out twice, the first derivative of your function used in the program is wrong. The correct expression for $f'\left(x\right)$ is
$$f'\left(x\right) = \cfrac{1}{1-e^x}+ \cfrac{xe^x}{\left(1-e^x\right)^2}+ \cfrac{k}{1-e^{-kx}}- \cfrac{k^2x e^{-kx}}{\left(1-e^{-kx}\right)^2}.$$

If you rectify this error, as Claude Leibovici has shown in his answer, the Newton-Raphson iteration requires mere four steps to converge to the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

If the  equation is
$$\frac 1y={\frac{x}{1-e^x}+\frac{k x}{1-e^{-k x}}-1}$$ with $y=0.64$ and $k=0.583$, the solution is $x=4.10048$

Using Newton with $x_0=0$, the iterates are
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & x_n \\
 0 & 0.00000 \\
 1 & 3.23752 \\
 2 & 4.08909 \\
 3 & 4.10047 \\
 4 & 4.10048
\end{array}
\right)$$

Even if you work with a constant derivative equal to $0.7915$ at $x=0$, you will converge to the same result after $15$ iterations.